# What is the name of the view in a Multiplication Table?

Tags: terminology

I have a question over this presentation of data which I do not know the name of. A [multiplication table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_table) presents

- two [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) which may or may the identical, in the case they are `[1..12]`
- a function computed over those sets.
- the result in a grid over input.

What would we call that? Does it have a name?

[image: Multiplication table]

Comment: a (pivoted) cartesian product?

Comment: I wonder why the numbers go up to 12. Is this a US/UK thing? I should probably ask at the math Education site.

Comment: We went up to 12 in school. Not sure if that's USA-specific.

Comment: They do the same in the UK. I wonder why, we only need up to 9.

Comment: I'm going to guess it has something to do with a foot having 12 inches? But I could be *totally* off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No consensus on a name

There doesn't seem to be a concrete name for this in any nomenclature. We can see in this thread for the [commit fest for PostgreSQL's \crosstabview](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/78543039-c708-4f5d-a66f-0c0fbcda1f76@mm#78543039-c708-4f5d-a66f-0c0fbcda1f76@mm). These alternative names suggested:

- gridview
- matrixview
- sheetview

It's a simple `pivot` but the argument is that SQL, the spec, doesn't permit this kind of pivot (queries that produce result sets with an undeterministic schema -- here the row count of input rows can change the amount of columns)

So, I'll go with @ypercubeᵀᴹ's suggestion

> a (pivoted) cartesian product?

Good as any other.